# Circles are generating with weird double vertices. How do I stop this?

Tags: modeling, vertices

When I go to Mesh > Circle, it creates a circle like normal, but in generates with these weird double vertices. How do I stop it from doing this? Merge by distance doesn't seem to work. [image]

Comment: are you sure that you have 1 circle? This looks like you created one circle and them somehow duplicated it in edit mode and moved it slightly... can you share your file?

Answer (score 0):

To give you a quick way to fix this. If you press M and merge by distance as you say on the bottom left of your viewport there is a small window that says merge by distance.
[image]

Increase the value of Merge Distance to get what you need. If the merge is succesfull a text showing this will appear.

[image]